# How to update properties of product from cart page using shopify api

Tags: shopify

I have added properties for add to cart but now how to update these properties with quantity using Shopify API

Answer (score 1):

You can update properties for line items in the cart by hitting Shopify's `/cart/change.js` endpoint.  This endpoint requires:

- Either a `line` number or an `id` - the `id` can either be the `item.id` (which is the same as the variant ID and therefore not guaranteed to be unique if you're using line-item properties) or the `item.key`, which *is* guaranteed to be unique.
- A 'new' `quantity` value - if unspecified, Shopify will default to quantity of `1` regardless of what the current quantity is, and
- A `properties` object, which will *replace* all properties currently on the line item. (It's therefore important to make sure you include all unchanged properties with their current values as well!)

So as an example (using jQuery - works just as well using raw XHR or Fetch, too):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/cart/change.js',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    id: item.key,
    quantity: item.quantity,
    properties: new_properties
  },
  success: function(cart){ /* Yay!  The cart updated! */ }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer but I can not change properties only change a quantity 
 by this API

I have put this code 
jQuery.ajax({
     url: '/cart/change.js',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
       id: variant_id,
       quantity: total_qty,
       properties: curLink
     },
     success: function(cart){ /* Yay!  The cart updated! */ }
   });

Comment: What are you passing in the `curLink` variable?

Comment: Also, if you're using line-item properties in your store, I strongly recommend avoiding `variant_id` as the ID (theme-wide), as two line items can have the same variant ID if they have different line-item props.  I strongly recommend using the item's `key` instead, as it is guaranteed to be unique.  Hitting `/cart/change` or `/cart/update` with variant IDs when the same variant is duplicated in the cart can have all sorts of unexpected side-effects.